# ffmpeg gives output file with 0 size

Tags: c#, ffmpeg

I'm using ffmpeg for audio conversion. I tried to convert recorded audio into mp3 format. I got the file but with 0 size. Can anyone help me to solve this?

Here is my code:

```
        Process ffmpegProcess;
        string strInputFile;
        string strOutputFile;
        strInputFile = Page.MapPath("audio.wav"); 
        strOutputFile = Page.MapPath("audio.mp3"); 
        ffmpegProcess = new Process();

        string fileargs = " -i ";
        fileargs += "\"" + strInputFile + "\"";
        fileargs += " \"" + strOutputFile + "\"";
        ffmpegProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = fileargs;
        ffmpegProcess.StartInfo.FileName = Page.MapPath("ffmpeg.exe");
        ffmpegProcess.Start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    Process ffmpegProcess;
    string strInputFile;
    string strOutputFile;
    strInputFile = Page.MapPath("audio.wav"); 
    strOutputFile = Page.MapPath("audio.mp3"); 
    ffmpegProcess = new Process();

    string fileargs = " -i ";
    fileargs += "\"" + strInputFile + "\"";
    fileargs += "-ab 192 -f mp3";
    fileargs += " \"" + strOutputFile + "\"";
    ffmpegProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = fileargs;
    ffmpegProcess.StartInfo.FileName = Page.MapPath("ffmpeg.exe");
    ffmpegProcess.Start();
```

Comment: Thank you but I am getting the same without any changes.

Comment: Now it is working. I just replace "-ab 192 -f mp3" with " -f mp3".